# Displaying ArcScene polygon extrusion edges?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, 3d-analyst, arcscene

When I extrude polygons in ArcScene 10.0, the polygon outlines are not displayed regardless of the symbol outline width/color.  Thus the extruded edges are not shown.  Here's a screenshot showing the problem with USA states. I need to outline each state at the top of it's extrusion.

How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you could make a second layer for your polygons and use some base height in order to put your symbolized polygons on top of the extruded polygons.

Alternatively, you can use the Layer 3D To Feature Class geoprocessing tool to convert your extruded buildings to [multipatches](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q8000000mv000000) in a new feature class

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  Your first workaround led to a solution:  I used the Feature to 3D by Attribute tool on the state polygon layer.  I then added that output layer to Arcscene without any extrusion, symbolized with no fill and a black outline.  Presto!  The state outline is now displayed at the top of each polygon.